# Reading csv file doesn't show anything?

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I am a beginner in `visual basic` and trying to import `csv` file into `datagridview`.

The sample code I used is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\test\text.txt")
    MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Application.DoEvents()
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            With DataGridView1
                .ColumnCount = 2
                Dim row As String() = New String() {currentRow(0), currentRow(1)}
                .Rows.Add()
            End With
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
            "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While
  End Using
End Sub
```

The data I am using is as follows:

```
Date,distance
1,5
2,8
4,9
10,15
```

However, I am getting blank `datagridview` after I import the `csv` file using above code.

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Might be stupid, but in file path section of your code, you wrote text.txt, not .csv

Comment: Yeah I forgot to change the extension of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following code

```
With DataGridView1
    ...
    .Rows.Add()
End With
```

you create an empty row by calling `Add` without any parameters.

You probably want to call

```
.Rows.Add(row)
```

Comment: How do I save the data in datagridview to new file ? Sorry for asking on the closed question. I tried to do this : `SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, DataGridView1.Rows)` but don't whether this is correct approach or not.

Comment: I suggest using a CSV library like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). It allows you to use a class to represent your data and read it into an array. You could then just bind it to the DataGridView and easily save it back to disk.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into Filehelpers